# Give parent elements a class when children is active with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Until recently XSLT was completely new to me, and I've been working on a menu/submenu in XSLT for a little while with a danish CMS called Dynamicweb.

I don't know if this is a Dynamicweb specific question or a XSLT related question, but I'll ask anyway.

My current XSLT document looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="//Page">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <li>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('', translate(translate(@MenuText, translate(@MenuText, $validRange, ''), ''), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))" />
        </xsl:attribute>

        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <!-- Add .inpath class -->
                <xsl:if test="@InPath='True'">
                    <xsl:text> inpath</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <!-- Add .firstitem class -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:text> firstitem</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <!-- Add .miditem class -->
                <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1 and position() &lt; count(//Page)">
                    <xsl:text> miditem</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <!-- Add .lastitem class -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = count(//Page)">
                    <xsl:text> lastitem</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>

                <!-- Add .active class -->
                <xsl:if test="@Active = 'True'">
                    <xsl:text> active</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Add link ID (URL friendly menu text) -->
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat('anchor-', translate(translate(@MenuText, translate(@MenuText, $validRange, ''), ''), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Add link URL -->
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="@FriendlyHref" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            </xsl:attribute>

            <!-- Add link text -->
            <span><xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></span>
        </a>
        <xsl:if test="count(Page) and @MenuText != 'Home'">
            <ul class="level{@AbsoluteLevel+1}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
                    <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>

</xsl:template>
```

You can see how I add classes based on Dynamicweb tags for `active` and `inpath`. The thing is that further down in the document <strike>(not pasted here)</strike> is a code for printing out submenu (`ul` and `li`). If I click a submenu item, that item gets the `active` class, but is there a way to give the parent the `active` class too?

**Update:** Added the raw XML (sorry for the messy XML).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NavigationTree>
  <Settings>
    <Pageview ID="1" AreaID="1" MenuText="Home" Title="Home" NavigationName="" />
    <Setting Level="1">
      <NavigationImage Value="" />
      <NavigationMouseoverImage Value="" />
      <NavigationActiveImage Value="" />
      <NavigationImgAfter Value="" />
      <NavigationDividerImage Value="" />
      <NavigationHideSpacer Value="True" />
      <NavigationSpace Value="0" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Level="2">
      <NavigationImage Value="" />
      <NavigationMouseoverImage Value="" />
      <NavigationActiveImage Value="" />
      <NavigationImgAfter Value="" />
      <NavigationDividerImage Value="" />
      <NavigationHideSpacer Value="" />
      <NavigationSpace Value="0" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Level="3">
      <NavigationImage Value="" />
      <NavigationMouseoverImage Value="" />
      <NavigationActiveImage Value="" />
      <NavigationImgAfter Value="" />
      <NavigationDividerImage Value="" />
      <NavigationHideSpacer Value="" />
      <NavigationSpace Value="0" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Level="4">
      <NavigationImage Value="" />
      <NavigationMouseoverImage Value="" />
      <NavigationActiveImage Value="" />
      <NavigationImgAfter Value="" />
      <NavigationDividerImage Value="" />
      <NavigationHideSpacer Value="" />
      <NavigationSpace Value="3" />
    </Setting>
    <Setting Level="5">
      <NavigationImage Value="" />
      <NavigationMouseoverImage Value="" />
      <NavigationActiveImage Value="" />
      <NavigationImgAfter Value="" />
      <NavigationDividerImage Value="" />
      <NavigationHideSpacer Value="" />
      <NavigationSpace Value="3" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
  <Page ID="1" AreaID="1" MenuText="Home" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=1" FriendlyHref="/default/home.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="True" ChildCount="3" class="L1_Active" Active="True" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
    <Page ID="6" AreaID="1" MenuText="News" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=6" FriendlyHref="/default/home/news.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    <Page ID="7" AreaID="1" MenuText="About" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=7" FriendlyHref="/default/home/about.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="2" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    <Page ID="8" AreaID="1" MenuText="Presence" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=8" FriendlyHref="/default/home/presence.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="3" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
  </Page>
  <Page ID="2" AreaID="1" MenuText="Hygiene" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=14" FriendlyHref="/default/hygiene.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="False" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="2" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="2" class="L1" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
    <Page ID="14" AreaID="1" MenuText="Professional" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=14" FriendlyHref="/default/hygiene/professional.aspx" Image="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_01.gif" ImageActive="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_02.gif" ImageMouseOver="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_02.gif" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="1" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
    <Page ID="15" AreaID="1" MenuText="Private" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=15" FriendlyHref="/default/hygiene/private.aspx" Image="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_01.gif" ImageActive="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_02.gif" ImageMouseOver="/Files/Navigation/menu_antibac_02.gif" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="2" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
  </Page>
  <Page ID="3" AreaID="1" MenuText="Household &amp; Leisure" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=3" FriendlyHref="/default/household---leisure.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="3" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L1" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
  <Page ID="4" AreaID="1" MenuText="Car Care" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=4" FriendlyHref="/default/car-care.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="4" LastInLevel="False" InPath="False" ChildCount="1" class="L1" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True">
    <Page ID="20" AreaID="1" MenuText="Carix" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=20" FriendlyHref="/default/car-care/carix.aspx" Image="/Files/Navigation/menu_carix_01.gif" ImageActive="/Files/Navigation/menu_carix_02.gif" ImageMouseOver="/Files/Navigation/menu_carix_02.gif" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="2" RelativeLevel="2" Sort="1" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L2" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
  </Page>
  <Page ID="5" AreaID="1" MenuText="Industrial Chemicals" MouseOver="" Href="Default.aspx?ID=5" FriendlyHref="/default/industrial-chemicals.aspx" Image="" ImageActive="" ImageMouseOver="" Title="" Allowclick="True" ShowInSitemap="True" AbsoluteLevel="1" RelativeLevel="1" Sort="5" LastInLevel="True" InPath="False" ChildCount="0" class="L1" Active="False" IsPagePasswordProtected="False" IsPageUserProtected="False" CanAccessPasswordProtectedPage="False" CanAccessUserProtectedPage="True" />
</NavigationTree>
```

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that (very probably). In any case, I would need a sample input document to write & test some XSLT for. Please add one to the question. :)

Comment: Your XML is all lower case, your XSLT is mixed case. What's correct?

Comment: Sorry, I put the XML through an XML prettifier :P Mixed case is correct!

Comment: Can you add it in mixed case, then? Thanks. ;-) `tidy -xml -w 1000 -iq` does a decent job prettifying XML without touching case.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the `tidy` command, thanks! Updated the XML now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a solution to your problem (and I have heavily modified your approach in the process):

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />
  <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
  <xsl:variable name="validRange" select="concat($upper, $lower)" />

  <xsl:template match="NavigationTree">
    <ul class="level1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
        <xsl:sort select="@Sort" data-type="number" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Page">
    <xsl:variable name="idText" select="
      translate(
        translate(@MenuText, translate(@MenuText, $validRange, ''), ''), $upper, $lower
      )
    " />
    <li id="{$idText}">
      <a href="{@FriendlyHref}" id="anchor-{$idText}">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:if test="position() = 1">firstitem </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1 and position() &lt; last()">miditem </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="position() = last()">lastitem </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="@InPath='True'">inpath </xsl:if>
          <!-- the descendant-or-self XPath axis solves your question! -->
          <xsl:if test="descendant-or-self::Page[@Active='True']">active </xsl:if>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <span>
          <xsl:value-of select="@MenuText" />
        </span>
      </a>

      <xsl:if test="Page">
        <ul class="level{Page/@AbsoluteLevel}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Page">
            <xsl:sort select="@Sort" data-type="number" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ul>
      </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in (when page 20 is set to "active"):

```
<ul class="level1">
  <li id="home">
    <a href="/default/home.aspx" id="anchor-home" class="firstitem inpath">
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level2">
      <li id="news">
        <a href="/default/home/news.aspx" id="anchor-news" class="firstitem">
          <span>News</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="about">
        <a href="/default/home/about.aspx" id="anchor-about" class="miditem">
          <span>About</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="presence">
        <a href="/default/home/presence.aspx" id="anchor-presence" class="lastitem">
          <span>Presence</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="hygiene">
    <a href="/default/hygiene.aspx" id="anchor-hygiene" class="miditem">
      <span>Hygiene</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level2">
      <li id="professional">
        <a href="/default/hygiene/professional.aspx" id="anchor-professional" class="firstitem">
          <span>Professional</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="private">
        <a href="/default/hygiene/private.aspx" id="anchor-private" class="lastitem">
          <span>Private</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="householdleisure">
    <a href="/default/household---leisure.aspx" id="anchor-householdleisure" class="miditem">
      <span>Household &amp; Leisure</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="carcare">
    <a href="/default/car-care.aspx" id="anchor-carcare" class="miditem active">
      <span>Car Care</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="level2">
      <li id="carix">
        <a href="/default/car-care/carix.aspx" id="anchor-carix" class="firstitem lastitem active">
          <span>Carix</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="industrialchemicals">
    <a href="/default/industrial-chemicals.aspx" id="anchor-industrialchemicals" class="lastitem">
      <span>Industrial Chemicals</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Be aware that you do not want `disable-output-escaping="yes"`, I've removed that since it would produce malformed XML.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! This looks much better than the original code :D

Comment: I have a quick follow up question. What can I test against to only print out a menu element if I'm on the parent page?

Comment: @rebellion: Define "being on the parent page".

Comment: I have three levels on my menu. I want the third one to be placed a different place than the two others. So far I've managed this. But this prints all level 3 menu items, and I want the items only correspondent to the active level 2 item. I know the CMS has something to say to this, but is there something I can test again too show (or hide) the menu if the active page don't have a submenu?

Comment: You are not making very much sense, I'm sorry. ;-) If you do not want to go beyond the second level in menu - well, simply prevent the recursion from going beyond level 2. `<xsl:if test="Page">` becomes `<xsl:if test="Page[@AbsoluteLevel &lt; 3]">`.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it good enough :/ The menu I have so far has two levels. If I add a subpage to a level 2 page, the menu is three levels. I want it to be maximum two, and the submenus for level three should only be visible when you're on level two pages, and the level 3 submenu should be a separate menu. Like this: http://cld.ly/8017la

Answer (score 5):

Well, a couple of observations:

1. You don't need the leading slashes in `match='//Page'`.  The XPath in the `match` attribute is used to select a template, not navigate to a node.
2. You don't need a `depth` parameter; since the depth of a `Page` is the number of `Page` ancestors it has, you can just use `count(ancestor::Page)` to calculate the depth.
3. If you want to get the `Active` attribute by walking up the tree of `Page` elements, use `ancestor-or-self::Page[last()]/@Active`.  The ancestor-or-self axis is a list of nodes that starts with the context node and includes its parent, its parent's parent, and so on, until the TLE is reached.  The `Page` part finds only `Page` elements on that axis, and the `[last()]` predicate finds the last of those `Page` elements, which will always be the highest-level `Page` element.
4. I strongly suspect that your use of `count(//Page)` is not going to serve you well in the long run.  That counts every single `Page` element in the source tree, irrespective of where it is found.  Is that really what you want?  Or do you want to know where the current `Page` element is relative to its sibling `Page` elements?  If so, you can just do `position() != 1 and position() != last()`.  This works because `position()` returns the context node's position relative to its expression context.  That is, when `xsl:apply-templates select='*'` is invoked, it creates a set of elements and finds a matching template for each.  That's the expression context; the third element in that list will have a `position()` of 3.
5. There's no need to do `test='count(Page)`.  `test='Page'` does the same thing; it evaluates to true if there's any child `Page` element.  It's both more readable and very likely faster.

**Edit**

Incorporated Tomalak's observation (see comments).

**Edit**

You know, I should actually read these questions.  In your context, to give a parent element a class when it or one of its *children* is active, the opposite of what I've done, you'd do:

```
<xsl:if test="@Active='True' or Page[@Active = 'True']">
    <xsl:text> active</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

But Tomalak's example, which uses the `descendant-or-self` axis, is more likely what you want to use, if the idea is to activate a menu if anything anywhere within it is active.  You could also do this:

```
<xsl:if test="@Active='True' or .//Page[@Active = 'True']">
    <xsl:text> active</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

as ".//" is really just a shortcut for `descendant::`.

Comment: +1 - Nice analysis! (P.S.: `ancestor-or-self::Page[last()]/@Active` works, too).

Comment: You know, I've been working with XSLT day in and day out since 1999 and that obvious idiom never even occurred to me.  I've probably got hundreds of occurrences of `X[position()=last()]` in my codebase.  Sheesh.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list. This helps a lot! Wasn't aware of many of the things that you mention (I only modified a template that shipped with the CMS). But I'm not sure how to use `ancestor-or-self::Page[last()]/@Active`. I tried using it in `<xsl:if test="">` but didn't work :/

Comment: @rebellion: Please post the XML you are dealing with. It is hard to debug a problem when you only have half of the code.

Comment: @Tomalak: The raw XML output is added!

Comment: The way you're doing the test, it should be `test='ancestor-or-self::Page[last()]/@Active = "True"'`.